# Proving a set of functions is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am trying to prove that $D(\mathbb{N}$)={ $f\in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ | f is a bijection such that $f(n)\neq n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$} is uncountable. So, I was thinking of showing $D(\mathbb{N})$ ~ $P(\mathbb{N})$ using Cantor Bernstein Theorem.

For the one direction, is it found to say since $D(\mathbb{N})\subset \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ ~$P(\mathbb{N})$ then there is an injection from $D(\mathbb{N})$ to $P(\mathbb{N})$?

I am not too sure how to go about the other direction. Should I show equinumerous to functions from $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ instead of using the power set?

Comment: Do you mean “such that for no integer $n$, $f(n)=n$” or do you mean “the function $f(n)$ is not the identity function.”

Comment: I think you can probably just diagonalize. Suppose you have a sequence $f_n$ of all such bijections, then construct a bijection $f$ so that $f(n)$ is neither $n$ nor $f_n(n)$ for each $n$. To do that, consider having a "running set" $A_n$ of numbers you haven't used yet prior to stage $n$, and then choose $f(n)$ to be any element of $A_n \setminus \{ n,f_n(n) \}$.

Comment: Strictly reading the notation, since the $n$ is not quantified, it would be yet another option: $D(\mathbb{N})=D_n(\mathbb{N})$ the functions that don't fix a given $n$. @StellaBiderman

Comment: Start with something easier, can you show that all injective functions has cardinality continuum ?

Comment: @StellaBiderman Sorry, I forgot to all what I was defining n to be.

Comment: @Ian That proof looks correct to me. Why don’t you post it as an answer.

Comment: @Ian Wouldn't using the Cantor Bernstein Theorem work here too?

Comment: @Pam_22R There’s a dozen ways to do it. The question is what falls within the scope of what you know and the scope of the problem, if you’ve been given limits on how to prove it. There is definitely a way to use CSB, the question is if it’s the simplest or easiest way (in this case, it seems to not be)

Comment: Well for the one direction wouldn't it be easiest to say since $D(\mathbb{N})$ is a subset of the functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ then we have an injection in that direction? Then we would just have to find the other injection.

Comment: Sure, but the other injection is not so obvious how to build.

Comment: @StellaBiderman My suggestion actually still has one serious, if subtle, flaw, which it would be instructive to the OP to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

Given $s:E\to \{1,2\}$ where $E$ is the even numbers define

$$f_s(2n)=4n+s(2n)$$
This satisfies $f_s(2n)\neq 2n$.

Now extend $f_s$ to an bijection st $f_s(n)\neq n$. There are many ways to do this, eg just define $f_s(2n+1)$ inductively to be the smallest allowed value.

Then $f_s$ is a bijection, satisfying your condition and $f_s\neq f_t$ for $s\neq t$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an injective map $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\to D$:
Given $A\subseteq\Bbb N$, defien $f_A\colon \Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ as
$$ f(n)=(n\operatorname \Delta 2)\operatorname \Delta 1_A(\lfloor n/2\rfloor)$$
where $\Delta$ is the binary "xor" operator and $1_A$ is the indicator fucntion of the set $A$. 
Xor'ing with 2 first ensures that $f_A$ has no fixpoints, xor'ing with the indicator function produces lots of variation.
(The above assumes $0\in\Bbb N$)

Note that this not onyl shows $D$ is uncountable, but even that it has continuum-cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be the set of binary sequences. Let $(a_n)\in B.$ If $a_1 = 0,$ we permute $1,2,3,4$ as follows: $1\to 2 \to 3\to 4 \to 1.$ If $a_1 = 1,$ we take the inverse of this permutation. We let $a_2$ "operate" on $5,6,7,8$ in exactly the same way ... Let this process percolate onwards to define an element of $D(\mathbb N).$ The map sending $(a_n)$ to an element of $D(\mathbb N)$ in this way is injective. It shows $D(\mathbb N)$ has at least the cardinality of $B,$ which is $c,$ the cardinality of the continuum.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to show that it is uncountable (without identifying what its cardinality actually is) is to just use the classic diagonal argument. Given a proposed enumeration $f_n$, we inductively define a function $f$ by introducing a set $A_0=\mathbb{N}$, then for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we define $f(n)$ to be an element of $A_{n-1} \setminus \{ n,f_n(n) \}$ and then define $A_n=A_{n-1} \setminus \{ f(n) \}$.

This produces an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself with no fixed points which is not in the given enumeration; it is not in the given enumeration because $\forall n \: f_n(n) \neq f(n)$. If additionally we perform the selection of $f(n)$ such that for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $k \not \in A_n$, then we have in fact constructed a bijection and so we are done. The simplest way to do that is to choose $f(n)=\min A_{n-1} \setminus \{ n,f_n(n) \}$.